# Atiny13, регистр сдвига, 7 светодиодов

Tags: c++, arduino

нашёл в интернете код но есть проблема

```
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <util/delay.h> 
 
#define HC595_PORT    PORTB 
#define HC595_DDR     DDRB 
#define HC595_DS_PIN  PB0    // Serial data (DS) 
#define HC595_SHCP_PIN PB1    // Shift register clock (SH_CP) 
#define HC595_STCP_PIN PB2    // Storage register clock (ST_CP) 
 
void hc595_shift_bit(uint8_t bit) { 
    if (bit) { 
        HC595_PORT |= (1 << HC595_DS_PIN); 
    } else { 
        HC595_PORT &= ~(1 << HC595_DS_PIN); 
    } 
 
  
    HC595_PORT |= (1 << HC595_SHCP_PIN); 
    HC595_PORT &= ~(1 << HC595_SHCP_PIN); 
} 
 
void hc595_shift_byte(uint8_t byte) { 
    for (int8_t i = 7; i >= 0; --i) { 
        hc595_shift_bit((byte >> i) & 0x01); 
    } 
} 
 
int main(void) { 
    HC595_DDR |= (1 << HC595_DS_PIN) | (1 << HC595_SHCP_PIN) | (1 << HC595_STCP_PIN); 
 

    for (int8_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { 
        hc595_shift_byte(1 << i); 
        HC595_PORT |= (1 << HC595_STCP_PIN); 
        HC595_PORT &= ~(1 << HC595_STCP_PIN); 
        _delay_ms(120); 
    } 
 
  
    _delay_ms(700); 
 
 
    for (int8_t i = 6; i >= 0; --i) { 
        hc595_shift_byte(1 << i); 
        HC595_PORT |= (1 << HC595_STCP_PIN); 
        HC595_PORT &= ~(1 << HC595_STCP_PIN); 
        _delay_ms(120); 
    } 
 
   
    _delay_ms(700); 
 
 
    for (int8_t i = 0; i < 8; --i) { 
        hc595_shift_byte(1 << i); 
        HC595_PORT |= (1 << HC595_STCP_PIN); 
        HC595_PORT &= ~(1 << HC595_STCP_PIN); 
        _delay_ms(120); 
    } 
 
   
    _delay_ms(700); 
 
 
    return 0; 
}
```

[видео работы этого кода](https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1Vhu2buS6GVrFMoEIEvmbZAYVuPT6ewBK&authuser=0)
я не знаю как заставить на втором проходе работать анимацию в другую сторону (тоесть не сверху вниз а наоборот) прошу помощи